# What is this shrub which survives in the Sonoran Desert naturally?

Tags: identification, shrubs, desert

Plants native to the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) require watering every 6 months. The following plant, which I am not sure is native to the Sonoran Desert or not, was found to thrive in the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) solely off rain.* What is this plant?

<sup>*Drip system piping can be seen in these pictures, but the system was not on for the past year.</sup>

[image: Shrub #3]
closeup:
[image: Shrub #3 closeup]